# Wondering about an etherscan transaction, did not receive swapped coin

Tags: dapps, etherscan, decentralized-exchange

May be a bit of an noobie question, as I am not super confident navigating etherscan at the moment.

I used the Bitswap dex from within the Trust Wallet app and swapped RSR for USDC.

On etherscan the transaction is showing a success but the USDC has not shown up in my wallet yet, nor is it showing the RSR has left the wallet nor any pending transaction.

Just wondering if someone wouldn't mind having a quick look and letting me know what might have gone wrong?

Thanks and much appreciated.

Here is the transaction hash:

```
0x3b52d2ff79d0b392f7bb1639a410017e1069883c041cbb96a10b53a5bc411c2f
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only did an approval.

Automated Market Makers usually need two transactions in order to trade your tokens :

1. Approve

You first call the ERC20 `approve` function to authorize the AMM to transfer your tokens on your behalf.

2. Swap

Then you send a second transaction to exchange the tokens.

You only did the first step. Try to check on the Bitswap RSR/USDC pair if you can send the swap transaction.

Comment: Ah thank you so much for the explanation and help. I opened the bitswap dex again but do not see the option to "swap" I see the approve function but when I click on that it just takes me to etherscan transaction so I am not sure how to send the "swap" transaction. Any ideas? or should I just try the first step again?

Comment: I don't know bitswap, you can try to reach their customer support.